# Array list size always 0, even after add data to it

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-volley, android-adapter

I want to display what my array list value is. So, I want to loop with the size of array list as the limit. But after I add some value through a function, and want to get the size of it, it always 0. I still newbie in android programming. I had search in google, but still confused and not understand what the problem is. Thanks for you guys help

I had tried to set through global variable, but it's not work

Here is my activity file

```
package bobby.irawan.aticket;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DetailPromoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private TextView nama_detail_promo_tv;
    private String nama_detail_promo;
    private DetailPromoAdapter adapter;
    private int counter_header=0, counter_promo = 0;
    private View layout_kupon;
    private int id_link_promo;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private String url = "192.168.11.134:8000";
    private TextView header_promo, kupon_promo, notif_promo;
    private ArrayList<DetailPromo> detailPromos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_promo);

        View view = findViewById(R.id.layout_kupon);
        header_promo = view.findViewById(R.id.header_promo_tv);
        kupon_promo = view.findViewById(R.id.kode_promo_tv);
        id_link_promo = (int) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("id_promo");
        nama_detail_promo = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("nama_promo");
        String nama_ota = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("nama_ota");
        listView = findViewById(R.id.lv_detpro);
        layout_kupon = findViewById(R.id.layout_kupon);
        header_promo = layout_kupon.findViewById(R.id.header_promo_tv);
        kupon_promo = layout_kupon.findViewById(R.id.kode_promo_tv);
        notif_promo = layout_kupon.findViewById(R.id.notif_promo_tv);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        nama_detail_promo_tv = findViewById(R.id.nama_detail_promo);
        nama_detail_promo_tv.setText(nama_detail_promo);
        setDetailPromotoClass(id_link_promo);

        adapter = new DetailPromoAdapter(detailPromos,this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Promo "+nama_ota);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //Set kupon
        System.out.println("Size detpro "+counter_header+" "+counter_promo);
        if(counter_header == 0 && counter_promo == 0){
            notif_promo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            header_promo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            kupon_promo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            System.out.println("Masuk sini");
        }
        else if(counter_header == 0){
            header_promo.setText("PROMO PESAWAT");
        }
        else{
            kupon_promo.setText("Tidak perlu");
        }

    }

    class DetailPromoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private List<DetailPromo> detailPromo;
        private Context context;

        public DetailPromoAdapter(List<DetailPromo> detailPromo, Context context) {
            this.detailPromo = detailPromo;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            System.out.println("Detail promo size"+detailPromo.size());
            return detailPromo.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.detail_promo_adapter, parent, false);
            TextView nama_detail_promo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.isi_detail_promo);
            if(detailPromo.get(position).getDetpro_role().equals("detail_promo")){
                nama_detail_promo.setText(detailPromo.get(position).getDetpro_list());
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public void setDetailPromotoClass(int id_linkpro){
        detailPromos = new ArrayList<DetailPromo>();
        String url_promo = "http://"+url+"/detail_promo/"+id_linkpro;
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url_promo, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject data_promo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        int id_detpro = data_promo.getInt("id");
                        int id_promo = data_promo.getInt("promo_id");
                        int id_linkpro = data_promo.getInt("linkpro_id");
                        String detpro_list = data_promo.getString("detpro_list");
                        String detpro_role = data_promo.getString("detpro_role");
                        detailPromos.add(new DetailPromo(id_detpro,id_promo,id_linkpro,detpro_list,detpro_role));
                        System.out.println("Data promo yang diklik "+id_promo+" "+id_linkpro+" "+detpro_list+" "+detpro_role);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        if(detpro_role.equals("header_promo")){
                            header_promo.setText(detailPromos.get(i).detpro_list);
                            System.out.println("Ada header");
                            counter_header++;
                        }
                        if(detpro_role.equals("kode_promo")){
                            System.out.println("Ada kupon");
                            kupon_promo.setText(detailPromos.get(i).detpro_list);
                            counter_promo++;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that your `onResponse(JSONObject response)` returns a value? Use a `Log.d` to print the result.

Comment: How to check it? Just log.d?

Comment: It's public void, so I don't think it return a value

Comment: add something like  `Log.d(TAG, "response = " + response.toString());` after your `onResponse` method to check if it's giving you a value.

Comment: `It's public void, so I don't think it return a value` yes, you're correct. What I meant is the result from the `response` parameter. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: List<detailspromo> promos = new Arraylist<>; try it.

Comment: where should i put it?

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך I tried it, and it return the value of json

Comment: ok, now try to move the `setDetailPromotoClass` calling after you've set the adapter with something like this:  `setDetailPromotoClass(id_link_promo);

adapter = new DetailPromoAdapter(detailPromos,this);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
setDetailPromotoClass(id_link_promo);`

Comment: Don't forget to check if your `jsonObject` is null or not whenever you need to check for the json value.

Comment: If I do it, my list view will be empty. Maybe it's because adapter.notifyDataSetChange in onResponse